# jQuery slider Orbit with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

ZURB's Orbit content slider is awesome. Just trying to get it working with Wordpress.

I was able to implement a similar but trimmed down plugin, [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). Was even able to use cycle in widget areas, which is nice.

Trying to accomplish the same with [Orbit](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider). Used chrome's console to make sure that javascripts and css were loading. Orbit div shows up, but just pinwheels... Could this have something to do with jQuery "$" shortcut not working in wordpress?

Thanks in advance for any help.

p.s. not sure what code is relevant to paste here... let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: edit: actually it was bxSlider that I was able to get working, not cycle. very cool slider, just doesn't have the pre-styling of orbit

Comment: And I just noticed Orbit working on one of the _pages for a second_ before it quit again... might make sense to someone